# Stylesheet formatting not working in Django project

Tags: html, css, django, django-templates

I have a HTML file which links stylesheets as follows:

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/font-awesome.min.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/animate.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/owl.carousel.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/owl.theme.default.min.css">
```

`index.html` is at the root of the project so when I open it the page is formatted as expected.

I tried to copy this css code to my Django project. I placed the `css` folder in the project root. The above html code is in `templates/base.html` and I run `python manage.py runserver` from the project root. When I do this the formatting doesn't work. I tried things like `href="css/bootstrap.min.css"` and even `/full/path/to/css/bootstrap.min.css` but they didn't work. I also tried `<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">` which does work.

How do I correctly reference stylesheets that are in a Django project folder?

**Additional Info.**

I any images on the site are stored in an AWS bucket. I think I remember reading something which suggested static files may also be hosted there. Here's an extract from my `settings.py` Is there something in it which might be causing a conflict?

```
# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'users.CustomUser'

LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = 'home'
LOGOUT_REDIRECT_URL = 'home'

CRISPY_TEMPLATE_PACK = 'bootstrap4'

EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.console.EmailBackend'
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.sendgrid.com'
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'apikey'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'password'
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True


MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')

AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME = 'lcc-media'
AWS_S3_REGION_NAME = 'eu-west-1'  # e.g. us-east-2
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = 'Access Key'
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = 'Secret Key'

# Tell django-storages the domain to use to refer to static files.
AWS_S3_CUSTOM_DOMAIN = '%s.s3.amazonaws.com' % AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME

# Tell the staticfiles app to use S3Boto3 storage when writing the collected static files (when
# you run `collectstatic`).
STATICFILES_LOCATION = 'static'
STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'custom_storages.StaticStorage'

# Tell the media app to use S3Boto3 storage when writing the media files
MEDIAFILES_LOCATION = 'media'
DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'custom_storages.MediaStorage'

# To deal with this: UserWarning: The default behavior of S3Boto3Storage is insecure and will change in django-storages
# 2.0. By default files and new buckets are saved with an ACL of 'public-read' (globally publicly readable). Version 2.0
# will default to using the bucket's ACL. To opt into the new behavior set AWS_DEFAULT_ACL = None, otherwise to silence
# this warning explicitly set AWS_DEFAULT_ACL.
# "The default behavior of S3Boto3Storage is insecure and will change "
AWS_DEFAULT_ACL = None
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should create a folder called **static** in your root folder and place your CSS folder in it.

Reference your static files with the following way:

```
{% load static %}
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/bootstrap.min.css' %}">
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried that but still had some issues so moved the `css` file from the `static` folder in my project root to the `static` folder in my AWS bucket. Seems to work now.

Answer (score 1):

{% load static %}
...
href="{% static 'css/stylesheet.css' %}"
(Add this code to main.py)
Use this static tag before adding css file.
And make a folder static and then in it store your css folder and .css file inside css folder. And try this.

In worst case(try this)
If in Case Not affecting in main html file then try to do all the styling stuffs in that main base.html file only. And try if any changes affecting or not!